# How to properly use the new asynchronous fragment loading

Tags: sapui5

OpenUI5 newbie here. I am trying to use OpenUI5 fragments, much like shown in the Walkthrough example, Step 16, in the documentation. I have a problem seeing how this can work properly.

The code below is a copy and paste from the Walkthrough example, Step 16, in the documentation:

```
onOpenDialog : function () {
  var oView = this.getView();

  // create dialog lazily
  if (!this.byId("helloDialog")) {
    // load asynchronous XML fragment
    Fragment.load({
      id: oView.getId(),
      name: "sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.view.HelloDialog"
      }).then(function (oDialog) {
        // connect dialog to the root view of this component
        oView.addDependent(oDialog);
        oDialog.open();
      });
  } else {
    this.byId("helloDialog").open();
  }
}
```

Since the HelloDialog fragment is loaded asynchronously, it is clear that the onOpenDialog function may return control to the user before the dialog has been created and opened. It is in the nature of asynchronous calls that we must not make any assumptions about how long it will take until the asynchronous code is executed. Anything is possible. Therefore, we must allow for the possibility that the user has control over the web page for any amount of time before the dialog shows up, say, several seconds. What is the user going to do? They're going to click the button for opening the dialog again, and again, and again, thereby creating the dialog multiple times, subverting the intended logic of the code. To be honest, I am not sure if I would be comfortable having that kind of thing in my code. How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general, you're right, the dialog could take time to load but usually, the process takes a fraction of time and the user should not see any "loading" time.

This is possible only if your dialog load data asynchronously too.

If you really want to be sure to give graphical feedback to the user you could do like this:

```
onOpenDialog : function () {
    var oView = this.getView();

    // create dialog lazily
    if (!this.byId("helloDialog")) {]
        // set the view to busy state
        oView.setBusy(true);
        // load asynchronous XML fragment
        Fragment.load({
            id: oView.getId(),
            name: "sap.ui.demo.walkthrough.view.HelloDialog"
        }).then(function (oDialog) {
            // remove the busy state
            oView.setBusy(false);
            // connect dialog to the root view of this component (models, lifecycle)
            oView.addDependent(oDialog);
            oDialog.open();
        });
    } else {
        this.byId("helloDialog").open();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I do have a follow-up question though. What I don't understand is this: if loading the fragment is so fast that a delay is not an issue, then why was the loading changed from synchronous to asynchronous in the first place? What was the rationale for that decision? Wouldn't we be better of with synchronous loading?

Comment: In general, you have to think about synchronous as the worst thing in the world. Really the worst one because it makes you (dev) lazy :D It's better to correctly handle async interaction with a correct UI/UX pattern instead of making the UI freeze because you're allowed to do that (load data synchronically). I think that this is something you have to start dealing with because it's the correct approach the UI5 will take from now on

Comment: I'm not following. We're not talking about loading data here. Of course I'm loading my entire OpenUI5 app asynchronously at the top. So now, my fragment, like everything else, has been loaded. The instantiation of the fragment is nothing more than the execution of some JavaScript code. Some object is newed, some initialization happens, something's inserted in the DOM. Are you saying that every time I manipulate my DOM, that should happen asynchronously? Why? What pattern are you referring to? Do you have a reference for that?